# Webpack client throwing an error when I run my nuxt app

Tags: axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have got this error when I tried to run nuxt app..

```
(index):1 EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.
```

here is my nuxt.config.js code

```
    require('dotenv').config()
const development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default {
  srcDir: 'resources/nuxt',
  mode: 'spa',

  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.APP_NAME,
    title: process.env.APP_NAME || '',
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/ico2.png' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v2.1.9/css/unicons.css'
      }
    ],
  laravel: { publicDir: 'public_html' },
  bootstrapVue: { icons: true },
  router: { base: '/' },
  axios: { baseURL: development ? process.env.DEV_URL : undefined },
  build: { extend(config, ctx) {} },
  server: {
    port: 8000
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to fetch some data from store which it is fetching the data from API Breakpoints like this :

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  apiItems: []
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_API(state, apiItems) {
    state.apiItems = apiItems
  }
}
export const actions = {
  async GET_API({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get('api/dummy_api')
    commit('SET_API', data)
  }
}
```

Inside My pages file :

```
async fetch({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch('adsl/GET_API')
})
```

Can anyone help !!

Comment: Please include your `nuxt.config.js` and any other relevant code, because it is almost impossible to help with this issue without that! Most probably there's an issue with the configured url-s, dev webserver, proxy, etc. Or if this issue comes up in your browser than the part of your code generating the error.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question to add some relevant code..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set application/json mime type at client and server side.

Here is PHP example for backend:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

axios example for frotend:

```
axios.get('my/url', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```